# How can I specify the return types in GCD blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

How can i specify the return types in GCD blocks? Here I want to return my result as `NSData` ...

```
- (NSData *)returnData:(NSString *)urlString{
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{   // here return type showing error

        NSString *strUrl = urlString;
        if([strUrl length] == 0)
            return nil; // from this point i want to stop the execution of the block and return nil .

        // otherwise only continue the left operations



    });         
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. An `async` block does not even start executing until some unknown time in the future (usually almost instantly, but there's no guarantee of that — it depends on what else is happening on the computer). I'll post an answer with an alternative implementation.

Comment: sorry , its not async ... its sync ....

Comment: Ah ok. Then it's very simple if it's sync instead of async. See my answer for a couple of options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (NSData *)returnData:(NSString *)urlString {
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    // Declare your local data outside the block.
    // `__block` specifies that the variable can be modified from within the block.
    __block NSData *localData = nil;

    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
        // Do something with `localData`...
        localData = somethingWonderful;
    });

    // `localData` now contains your wonderful data.
    return localData;
}
```

The block's format (parameters/return type) are specified in the function's signature. In this case, `dispatch_sync` uses a block with no return type and no parameters. If you want further variables to work with you need to declare them outside the block, as in the code above.

Comment: You don't want that 'return localData' there.

Comment: He does, but he needs to pull it out of the block and leave it in the function instead.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant by "there" (within the block).

Comment: Yep, thanks - I realised just after you made the comment - corrected ;)

Comment: Sorry for noob question, bus is this thread safe? If thread #1 just quitted the block, and thread #2 enters the block and finishes it before thread #1 returns, won't thread #1 return the value intended for thread #2?

Answer (score 4):

Since a block shares the scope with the parent, it's easiest not to specify a return type at all. For example:

```
- (NSData *)returnData:(NSString *)urlString{
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    __block NSData *data; // the __block keyword allows this variable to be changed by a block

    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^(NSData *)){   // here return type showing error

        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];

    });         

    return data;
}
```

If you do want to specify a return type, then you cannot use `dispatch_sync()`, because it only accepts blocks with no return type. An example of how to use blocks manually is:

```
typedef NSData *(^MyDataBlock)();
MyDataBlock getData = ^ NSData *() {
  return [NSData data];
};

NSData *data = getData();
```

Note that because you are not using `dispatch_sync()` in the second example this code will execute *immediately* on the current queue instead of waiting until there is some available CPU time. Waiting for the CPU have some idle time can actually be faster than executing it immediately.

The advantage is this approach is much more flexible, you can pass the `getData` variable around to other methods and so on, and they could even execute it inside their own `dispatch_sync()` call to take advantage of GCD's priority system.

Comment: Just a little clarification: dispatch_sync won't necessarily cause the block to execute immediately. The block will be enqueued like any other block. The difference is that the calling thread will block (as in pause) until this queued block completes. That may be some time in the future, it depends on that target queue.

Comment: @FirozeLafeer because the CPU core which calls `dispatch_sync()` is idle while waiting for the block to finish, there's a very good chance it will execute instantly, unless the queue is unusually backed up.

Comment: Or there are other threads and queues in flight. You can't assume the CPU core is suddenly idle just because this one thread is blocked, can you? Or the target queue could be a serial queue with n other blocks ahead of you in the queue. I was just making the point that dispatch_sync isn't "do this immediately", it's "enqueue this block and I'll sit here and wait for it". That's an important difference in the cases where you typically use this function.

Answer (score 1):

What's the exact error you're seeing? Because this line

```
dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^(NSData *)){   // here return type showing error
```

has a syntax error. You've got a stray `)` after your block argument list.

Even if you fix that, you have another problem, which is that you're trying to return a value from a block passed to `dispatch_sync()`, and yet `dispatch_sync()` expects a block that returns `void`. It seems that what you're really trying to do is return the data from the function, but to do this you need to pass the data from the block back to your outer function. You can do this with a `__block`-qualified variable, like this:

```
- (NSData *)returnData:(NSString *)urlString{
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = 
    dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    __block NSData *localData = nil;

    dispatch_sync(concurrentQueue, ^{
        if ([urlString length] == 0) {
            // we don't have any data to return
            return; // localData is already nil
        }
        // calculate localData
        localData = ...;
    });
    // Now localData should be populated
    return localData;
}
```

Comment: Very thanks , i am facing one more problem here , please check my edited question ...

Comment: @user817506: You can just stick a `return` in your block to exit early. I'll edit my post to show an example

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Frioze's caution:  if you you call any API not recommended for use on the main thread on the queue you _sync to, and you call dispatch_sync from the main thread you may as well have called that API from the main thread as you have asked to wait for it to complete.   This is true not just for the block in your _sync call, but also for any prior blocks sent via _async that have not yet completed.